# Meaning of the icons next to Trello board names

Tags: trello

What do the icons next to the board name mean? Some have a lock. And some have two people.

Is there a general explanation of all icons somewhere? Would be useful in knowing what these represent or mean in relation to the boards they appear alongside.

Answer (score 5):

The icons you're referring to indicate the "visibility" of the board (or organization)

[image: Trello Permissions Icons]

[image: green dot] (**green dot**) means the board (or organization) is **"Public"**.  It is visible to anyone (even people without Trello accounts)

[image: two people] (**"two people"**) means the board is visible only to members of the **organization** that the board belongs to.

[image: lock] (**lock**) means that the board (or organization) is **private**.  A private board is only visible to members of the board, and a private organization is only visible to members of the organization.

(In some contexts, if you hover your mouse over one of the icons, a tooltip will pop up explaining what the icon means.)